# How to find the memory requirement (RAM) when network load is know on raspberry

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, memory

I am want to use the Raspberry Pi for my experimental work. My network load will be approximately 2000bits. How I can find the memory (RAM) requirement against the network load? Which formula can be used for finding the memory requirement?

Comment: The network load does not directly correlate to ram usage.  2000bits Total? Per Second?   Is that sending or receiving? Whats the data?  The RAM usage is going to be determined by what processes are running that are sending/receiving this data, and what they have to do with it.  Basically you have not given enough information to actually give you an answer. And really I don't think there is an ANSWER, but more detail might help point you in the right direction.

Comment: I can see no relevance to the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying driver buffers are static and reused but this message is likely copied several times up and down the IP stack including possibly dynamic buffers with kmalloc .

I would estimate a 2x instantaneous  overhead in raw  memory use for a given Ethernet frame, plus a copy for every thread that is reading the packet.

But it is not clear how you would profile this or how relevant it is to the actual memory commit as this memory is cleared in kernel as soon as it is handed off and kernel memory is seperate. Additionally  Every process is responsible for managing the memory of any packet copies it keeps.

Perhaps you can rephrase the question to address your actual concern or performance issue